# Matlab Calling Functions without parentheses

Tags: matlab, function, parentheses

What is the correct name for the situation where a Matlab-script calls a function, but provides arguments without parentheses?

Example:

```
clear xx
```

Alternatively, I could use parentheses and transfer a string with the variable name:

```
clear('xx')
```

How can I distinguish between both alternatives when googling for a solution?

*Bonus Question:* How can I put the content of a variable into a call that is NOT using parentheses? Specifically, a build-script using mcc with a dynamic -o *filename* option; calling mcc with parentheses would also be acceptable, but I don't know how to google that, hence this question.

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92537-how-do-i-pass-arguments-into-and-out-of-my-standalone-executable

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. This deals with calling the compiled executable from the shell. I'm asking about the difference within matlab scripts, so *.m-files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call a function without the brackets, it is called **command syntax**. Here are three links to relevant documentation:

- [syntax](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html#f76-1098266)
- [command vs function syntax](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html)
- [scripts and functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts-and-functions.html)

---

*Bonus answer*

You cannot use a variable when using command syntax. From the docs:

> When calling a function using command syntax, MATLAB passes the arguments as character vectors.

So it would work like so:

```
abc = zeros(10); % Some matrix called abc
mystring = 'abc' % A string containing the variable name
% Option 1:
clear('abc')     % Clears the variable abc
% Option 2:
clear abc        % As per above docs quote, interpreted as clear('abc')
% Option 3:
clear mystring   % As per option 2, interpreted as clear('mystring') so doesn't work
% Option 4:
clear(mystring)  % Interpreted as clear('abc') so works as expected
```

When calling `mcc` as you suggest in the question, the tooltip shows you can in fact use function syntax, despite the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/mps/ml_code/mcc.html) being entirely shown using command syntax.

[image: tooltip]

---

*Notes*

Using brackets is standard practise in MATLAB, since you also cannot get output values from a function when using command syntax.

Also from the 3rd docs link above, you can see a message discouraging the use of command syntax when using MATLAB.

> **Caution:** While the unquoted command syntax is convenient, in some cases it can be used incorrectly without causing MATLAB to generate an error.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation and links! I figured I can call mcc in this way: mcc('-m', 'script.m', '-d', pathVariable); and it works fine, even though this seems undocumented.

Comment: I just saw your edit about mcc, thanks for that, too!

Comment: No worries, it is odd that the documentation uses only command syntax, I assume it's because people using the compiler are assumed to be more familiar with that style. I don't know of (and assume there aren't) any functions which are exclusively called using the command syntax.