# How to run run mcc in a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, mcc

I need help to use `mcc -mv` in a for loop. 
Specifically, I have matlab files names as `Myfiles_k.m` where `k` runs from `1:n`. 
I want to do something like the following

```
for i=1:n 
fname = ['Myfiles_',num2str(i),'.m']; 
mcc -mv fname
end
```

This leads to the following error:

> Could not determine type of the MATLAB file 'fname'. Please make sure that you are compiling MATLAB Program files.

Could anyone help with letting me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab Calling Functions without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234314/matlab-calling-functions-without-parentheses)

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
mcc -mv fname
```

is interpreted as

```
mcc('-mv','fname')
```

That is, the arguments are seen as strings. You have a variable containing a string you want to pass to `mcc`, this requires:

```
mcc('-mv',fname)
```