# MATLAB, Octave: working with folder names that have space in them

Tags: string, matlab, octave, directory

In MATLAB, actually Octave, I would like to find a list of all subfolders in the current folder so I use this:

```
subFolder = dir;
```

This gives the list of all subfolders in the current folder. This returns a structure whose one element is the name. Assume I have two subfolders with names `subfolder 1A` and `subfolder 1B`.

Now I want to go to these folders. Then I do this:

```
cd subFolder(1).name
```

But I get this error:

```
error: subFolder(1).name: No such file or directory
```

If I do this:

```
cd "subfolder 1A"
```

everything works fine. What is the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space in the folder name is a red herring in this case. It's not the source of the problem. The actual issue is that you need to call the [`cd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) function using [function syntax instead of command syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) (i.e. use parentheses; related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45234314/52738)):

```
cd(subFolder(1).name);
```

When you use the command syntax, `subFolder(1).name` is itself being treated as the string argument to `cd` (i.e. it's looking for a folder called `'subFolder(1).name'`). With the function syntax, the string contained *within* the structure array field is used as the argument.

To make your code a little more robust, you could also use the `'folder'` field returned by [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html):

```
cd(fullfile(subFolder(1).folder, subFolder(1).name));
```

This will go to the desired folder regardless of the directory you are currently in, since it specifies an absolute path instead of a partial path (which is relative to the current directory).