# Difference between help func and help(func) in Octave

Tags: octave

The `help` function works differently when used as `help func` compared to `help(func)`.

For example, executing `help mvnrnd`, displays the desired output:

```
>> help mvnrnd
'mvnrnd' is a function from the file /home/student/octave/statistics-1.4.0/mvnrnd.m

 -- Function File: S = mvnrnd (MU, SIGMA)
 -- Function File: S = mvnrnd (MU, SIGMA, N)
 -- Function File: S = mvnrnd (..., TOL)
     Draw N random D-dimensional vectors from a multivariate Gaussian
     distribution with mean MU(NxD) and covariance matrix SIGMA(DxD).

     MU must be N-by-D (or 1-by-D if N is given) or a scalar.

     If the argument TOL is given the eigenvalues of SIGMA are checked
     for positivity against -100*tol.  The default value of tol is
     'eps*norm (Sigma, "fro")'.

Additional help for built-in functions and operators is
available in the online version of the manual.  Use the command
'doc <topic>' to search the manual index.

Help and information about Octave is also available on the WWW
at http://www.octave.org and via the help@octave.org
mailing list.
```

While executing `help(mvnrnd)`, produces error:

```
>> help(mvnrnd)
error: 'Sigma' undefined near line 22 column 50
error: called from
    mvnrnd
```

I thought `help func` and `help(func)` where the same, but it seems that there are some differences which I couldn't find while searching online. Any ideas?

I have also tried creating my own function, for example:

```matlab
function hello()
  % Whatsup
  print("hello")
end
```

And has the same behavior. Executing `help hello` works fine, whereas error occurs when executing `help(hello)`. It is like it's trying to execute the code inside the function, because the stack trace has references to the code of the function and its calling functions. This is the output:

```
>> help(hello)
warning: print.m: fig2dev binary is not available.
Some output formats are not available.
warning: called from
    __print_parse_opts__ at line 388 column 9
    print at line 316 column 8
    hello at line 3 column 3
error: print: no figure to print
error: called from
    print at line 341 column 5
    hello at line 3 column 3
```

P.S: For `mvnrnd` to be accessible, the package `statistics` must be loaded:

```
pkg load statistics
```

Comment: `help hello` is equivalent to `help('hello')` (note the quotes). The command syntax always makes strings of all arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab Calling Functions without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234314/matlab-calling-functions-without-parentheses) <— this answer gives more detail about this syntax.

Comment: Hello @cris-luengo, thanks for considering my answer. I still do not understand, why it does not work with double quotes and why it seems like it is trying to run the given function (according to the stack trace)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB language seems to have functions (such as `sum`) as well as commands (such as `help`). However, it knows only functions. The "command syntax" is where you leave off the parentheses when calling a function. Whatever follows the function name is split at spaces and interpreted as strings, which are passed as arguments to the function. Therefore,

```matlab
help mvnrnd
```

is the same as

```matlab
help('mvnrnd')
```

(and note that in Octave, the double quote is equivalent to the single quote, so `help("mvnrnd")` would also be the same thing; in MATLAB the double quote has a different meaning).

You can read more about this syntax in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234314/matlab-calling-functions-without-parentheses).

When you write

```matlab
help(mvnrnd)
```

then Octave first interprets the argument to the function, `mvnrnd`, trying to run that function without any arguments (in the MATLAB language, `mvnrnd` is the same as `mvnrnd()`). If this didn't produce an error, it would call `help` with whatever output `mvnrnd` generates.

Let's try an experiment:

```matlab
function out = myfunc
   % This is help for the function myfunc
   out = 'sum';
end
```

Now we see that:

```
>> help myfunc
'myfunc' is a function from the file /home/cris/octave/myfunc.m

 This is help for the function myfunc

>> help('myfunc')
'myfunc' is a function from the file /home/cris/octave/myfunc.m

 This is help for the function myfunc

>> help(myfunc)
'sum' is a built-in function from the file libinterp/corefcn/data.cc

 -- sum (X)
 -- sum (X, DIM)
 -- sum (..., "native")
 -- sum (..., "double")
 -- sum (..., "extra")
     Sum of elements along dimension DIM.
```

That is, in the 3rd case, `myfunc` returned `sum`, and now `help` shows the help for function `sum`.